# Changing configuration options for Marathon

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I'd like to change set various configuration options for Marathon, and I'm unsure how to do this. For example, I'd like to add `--event_subscriber http_callback` to the launch command.

Comment: What Operating System are you using, and how was Marathon launched/installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each configuration you can create a file in the directory /etc/default/marathon where the filename is the name of the option and a single line in the file containing the value for that option.

Eg. Make a file /etc/default/marathon/event_subscriber that contains the line "http_callback"

This also works for mesos.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the directory has to be `/etc/marathon/conf`. This is valid for **0.11.1**.

Comment: To improve your answer, please reference the answer you are refereeing to.